# Sidebar with Affix not working

Tags: html, css, affix

I'm not really a developer but I'm ok with HTML and CSS. I'm trying to build a site with Bootstrap 3.3.7 and I've taken some code from [an example](https://www.codeply.com/go/1i2osA2FZE/bootstrap-bootstrap-3-affix-sidebar) I found at Codeply to have a sidebar stick when the user scrolls down.

However, when I paste their code into my page, the sidebar doesn't stick. It just scrolls past the sidebar. Since I'm not very experienced, I've probably made a silly mistake somewhere but I'm stumped.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-
 to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sidebar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<title>

</title>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-
  target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Explorify</a>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>

<div id="masthead">  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <h1>Tongues
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div><!--/container-->
</div><!--/masthead-->

<!--main-->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <!--left-->
  <div class="col-md-3" id="leftCol">
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
      <li><a href="#sec0">Section 0</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sec1">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sec2">Section 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sec3">Section 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sec4">Section 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/left-->

  <!--right-->
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <h2 id="sec0">Content</h2>
    <p>
      At Bootply we like to build simple Bootstrap templates that utilize 
      the code Bootstap CSS without a lot of customization. Sure you can 
      find a lot of Bootstrap themes and inspiration, but these templates 
      tend to be heavy on customization.</p>

    <hr>
    <p>
      Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
      architecto beatae vitae 
      </p>

    <h2 id="sec1">Content</h2>
    <p>
      Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
      architecto beatae vitae 
      dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit 
      aspernatur aut odit aut.
    </p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Hello.</h3></div>
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
            adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
            Quisque mauris augue
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <hr>
    <h2 id="sec2">Section 2</h2>
    <p>
      Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
      architecto beatae vitae 
    </p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"><img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="img-
      responsive"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="img-
      responsive"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="img-
      responsive"></div>
    </div> 
    <hr>
    <h2 id="sec3">Section 3</h2>
    <p>
      Images are responsive sed @mdo but sum are more fun peratis unde omnis 
    </p>
    <p>
      Fos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, 
      qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, 
    </p> 
    <h2 id="sec4">Section 4</h2>
    <p>
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem </p>

    <hr>
    <h4><a href="http://www.bootply.com/Gygh9swISB">Edit on Bootply</a></h4>
    <hr>

    </div><!--/right-->
</div><!--/row-->
</div><!--/container-->
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Apologies for posting the entire index.html but I'm wondering if it has something to do with how I've linked the javascript. I pasted the js code from the example into scripts.js and the CSS into style2.css.

I appreciate any help the community could give me!

Answer (score -1):

I dont know exactly what your mistake is but I guess you referenced different js and css files than the codeply or referenced them in the wrong order.

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/rd3rpkj5/) for a working version. (Make sure to increase the width of the result page though..)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code, with everything in the HTML doc works when I try it. I guess that confirms my suspicion that I was linking my stylesheets incorrectly but I can't figure out why. I wish I could see how the Codeply example linked them up. Thanks!

Comment: Although I'm noticing now that clicking the menu options from the Codeply example sends you slightly below the section header. Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: I think thats because the navbar is above where it should send you

Comment: Increasing the padding of each section could fix this. For example: `<h2 style ="padding-top:80px;" id="sec0">Content</h2>`

Comment: Good tip, thanks. One last thing that's bugging me. The active state on the sidebar doesn't seem to be working for me, even though I literally just copied your code. It seems to default to Section 4 as orange for some reason and clicking the others doesn't change it.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know what causes that problem